# should input boxes be cleared out onclick

Tags: html

I have a design question. I have a few input boxes in my form with some default values (numbers). I was wondering if I should have a mechanism to blank them out when user clicks on the box to change them. It would look cool. But if I leave them as it is, it might just be more useful for the user in case he wants to alter only a few digits or copy the figure..

I apologize if this is not the right forum for this type of questions.

Comment: Forum you are looking for is http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. Posted it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a placeholder-attribute for input like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Some text" />
```

**[JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/6C4VX/)**

The text "**Some text**" will disappear if the user takes some input.

This snipplet doesn't require any javascript and is really nice i think. Have Fun!

Comment: Thanks Tim but I want to know whether I should do it or not. It is not a placeholder. A placeholder is the value which surely will get changed since it is not valid input value. Mine is a dynamically assigned default value which would work if user doesn't change it.

Comment: Okay. Then you can do stuff like "mark all text in box if clicked" rather than delete all content

Comment: I think this makes sense. I got same response from stackexchange too. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't. Beware of "creeping featurism" :) 
Just have the  above saying e.g. "your phone number", people should manage.

Here's the simplest possible way of removing the digits on "click":
HTML

```
     <input  name="" type="text" value="2">
```

JS:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    $('input').click(function(){

    $(this).val('');
    });

});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k47L4/

Comment: Thanks Andrey, please check my comment to Tim. It is not a placeholder per say but a default value...

Comment: I see. Then Captain Code was right, you should ask on ux.stackexchange.com. Try to provide a bit more context too, e.g. who's the target visitor, purpose of the form. It might be useful for whoever answers there.